# CiviCRM - CiviContribute does not respect the invoice number prefix set in the CiviContribute Component Settings

Tags: invoice, civicrm

I have been using the CiviContribute for a short while and it's quite good, but there is something that I could never make work.
Note: I use Civi on Wordpress.
In the Admin > Civicontribute > CiviContribute Component Settings, you can set the "Invoice Prefix" to whatever text you want, but when you go to the actual contribution in the dashboard and click View, the Invoice Number has the default prefix "INV_1".
Another example is: I used in the invoice template the {contribution.invoice_number} token and the same behavior, default prefix...
Does anyone have any experience with this or knows a fix?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try https://civicrm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! I actually did right after posting here and I will update here too if I get any answer. :)

Comment: This was answered on my question from [civicrm.stackexchange.com](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/civicrm-civicontribute-does-not-respect-the-invoice-number-prefix-set-in-the-c)<br>
Thanks!